# Identify this strategic, war board & card game about Italy (not Carcassonne)?

Tags: identify-this-game

The name of this game was a word I'm not familiar with, probably an italian word, starting with a C and around 8 to 12 letters long (it wasn't Carcassonne!)

The goal of the game was to conquer 3 adjacent or any 5 territories in Italy by going to war with your fellow players.

Players would have a hand of 10 cards. The cards had point values that, when played, determined whose army was most powerful that round. Some of the cards were yellow, some red. Some of the cards were: Cardinal, Spring, Winter, Female Hero (ala Joan of Arc?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [Condottiere](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/112/condottiere).

From Board Game Geek's description:

> The object of Condottiere is to acquire four connected provinces in renaissance Italy. To do this players auction off different provinces on the board and bid on these provinces with a hand of cards representing mercenaries, seasons, scarecrows, and political figures.